# Design dynamic row header, column header and content in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datatable, datarow

I want to have an itemsource which provides binding to column header, row header and its content in MVVM pattern. I've tried DataTable, however, I don't know how to fill the row header. It is possible to fill the rowheader during adding DataRow?

```
DataRow dr = new DataRow();
dr.ItemArray = current.Split(new char[] { '\t' });
// add row header?
```

Please help.

Answer (score -1):

This is what you want?

XAML code:

```
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="SimpleDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" />
</Grid>
```

Creating new data row:

```
private void CreateNewDataRow()
{
    // Use the MakeTable function below to create a new table.
    DataTable table;
    table = MakeNamesTable();

    // Once a table has been created, use the  
    // NewRow to create a DataRow.
    DataRow row;
    row = table.NewRow();

    // Then add the new row to the collection.
    row["fName"] = "John";
    row["lName"] = "Smith";
    table.Rows.Add(row);

    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(column.ColumnName);
    }

    SimpleDataGrid.DataContext = table;
}
```

Creating new columns:

```
private DataTable MakeNamesTable()
{
    // Create a new DataTable titled 'Names.'
    DataTable namesTable = new DataTable("Names");

    // Add three column objects to the table.
    DataColumn idColumn = new DataColumn();
    idColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Int32");
    idColumn.ColumnName = "id";
    idColumn.AutoIncrement = true;
    namesTable.Columns.Add(idColumn);

    DataColumn fNameColumn = new DataColumn();
    fNameColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    fNameColumn.ColumnName = "Fname";
    fNameColumn.DefaultValue = "Fname";
    namesTable.Columns.Add(fNameColumn);

    DataColumn lNameColumn = new DataColumn();
    lNameColumn.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String");
    lNameColumn.ColumnName = "LName";
    namesTable.Columns.Add(lNameColumn);

    // Create an array for DataColumn objects.
    DataColumn[] keys = new DataColumn[1];
    keys[0] = idColumn;
    namesTable.PrimaryKey = keys;

    // Return the new DataTable. 
    return namesTable;
}
```

Calling CreatingNewDataRow():

```
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();

   CreateNewDataRow();
}
```

For more information, please see:

[DataRow Class MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx)

[DataTable.NewRow Method MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx)

Comment: It doesn't answer the question.